# Jmeter distributed testing in different VLAN

Tags: jmeter

I have my load generators in different VLAN's .Which I want to connect and perform Load Tesing .Kindly Suggest ways to achieve this?
I had done Jmeter distributed testing in same VLANs making 1 Master and 10 slaves . But in different VLANs I am unable to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter master communicates with slaves using [RMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) which works on top of [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)

It means that JMeter master needs to be able to reach the slave and vice versa. Slaves don't have to "see" each other.

So you either need to [set up routing between VLANs](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/routing-between-vlans/) or connect master and all the slaves which are not in the same VLAN as the master to the [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), the fastest and the easiest option is most probably [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/), and use tun/tap interfaces instead of normal NIC IP addresses.

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)